# eloquent only get first Active query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

hey guys i have a confusing question

I have 3 tables

1. basket_lists (carts)
2. basket_items (carts_item)
3. products

with this migrate

```
 'basket_lists':
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->boolean('active');
        $table->timestamps();


    basket_items:
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_Id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('basket_list_id');
        $table->timestamps();


       products:
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->bigInteger('amount');
        $table->timestamps();
```

I have some products in my table , when i search (query) {

```
BasketList::where('active', '=', 1)->with('basketItems.products')->get();
```

it only gives me the first basketlist products (where id = 1)
if i insert new basketlist and set the first basketlist to (active = 0) and second one to (active = 1) it will not show any products.

Here is my model classes :

```
class BasketList extends Model
{
    public function basketItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(BasketItem::class ,'basket_list_id' );
    }
}

class BasketItem extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class,'id' );
    }


    public function basketList()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(BasketList::class);
    }

}


public function basketItem() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo(BasketItem::class ,'product_id');
}
```

Comment: dash ali ye mosbat behet dadam hal koni ;) chizi be name products nadareim. chun har item faghat motalegh be ye product hast. pas rabete hasMany() ghalate. bayad belongTo bezari.

Comment: oon bande khoda ham dorost javab dade. age kar nemikone shayad to product_Id ro product_id minevesi yeja. be horufe kuchik va bozorg deghat kon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must change your relationship to belongsTo()

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class BasketItem extends Model
    {
        //
        protected $table = 'basket_items';


        public function product()
        {
                return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id','id' ); // Watch out for the case sensitive. how did you wright product_id in your migration. (product_id or product_Id)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You break Laravel default naming conventions for foreign keys 'product_**I**d'

It must be `'product_id'`

> Eloquent determines the foreign key of the relationship based on the
>   model name. In this case, the `BasketItem` model is automatically
>   assumed to have a `'product_id'` foreign key. If you wish to override this
>   convention, you may pass a second argument to the hasMany method:

**Fix**

App\BasketItem.php

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_Id','id' );
}
```

Check [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

**Usage**

```
BasketList::where('active', '=', 1)->with('basketItems', 'basketItems.product')->get();
```

Comment: thanx for answering ! but it was not the answer ! i did fix that and nothing change @FouedMOUSSI

Comment: Regarding your db schema you must change products() method relationship from hasMany to belongsTo in your BasketItem model. 
See updated answer

Comment: Watch out for the case sensitive. product_id or product_Id